What are the conditions for a force field to be "consistent with special relativity"?
I'm trying to gain a deeper understanding of a certain exercise I came across (Source: "Problem Book In Relativity and Gravitation", Exercise 2.15):

A new force field $F^\mu(x^\nu)$ is discovered which induces a 4-acceleration $$a^\mu \equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}u^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = m^{-1}F^{\mu}(x^\nu) $$
on a particle of mass $m$, at position $x^\nu$. Notice that $F^\mu$ does not depend on $u^\nu$. Show that this force is not consistent with special relativity.

The first thing that occurred to me when seeing this was that the four acceleration produced by such a force won't necessarily satisfy the condition of being orthogonal to the four velocity. Since for a four velocity $\mathbf{u}$ we always have $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{u} = -c^2$ then we can write:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\left(\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{u} \right) = \mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{a} = 0 $$
So looking at the solution given in the book, I saw that they basically gave the same argument. However, they also add a remark I'm not entirely sure I understand:

If $\mathbf{F}$ is not to be identically zero then for some 4-velocity $\mathbf{u}$, the product $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{u}$ must be nonzero.

The thing I don't completely understand here is where exactly a condition was put that implies "$\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{u}$ must be nonzero". Is it the point where the exercise stated "Notice that $F^\mu$ does not depend on $u^\nu$"?
I can understand the four-force has to be dependent on $u^\nu$ insofar as the four acceleration is the proper time derivative of $u^\nu$. But then it seems to me to beg the question, of how can we ever define any four-force that is consistent with special relativity, apart from just differentiating the four momentum with respect to proper time and defining it to be a general four-force.
In other words, If I wanted to invent a "new force field" that would be consistent with special relativity, how would it look? What condition do we need to modify to make it consistent with special relativity?

bold font $\bf u$ is supposed to be a 3-vector, while $u$ or of needed $u_0$ is the time component, and the together make the 4-vector $u_{\mu}$ or $u^{\mu}$. Classic example is the 4-wave vector ($c=1$): $k_{\mu} = (k, {\bf k})$.

@JEB I'm fine with that convention but I think the word "supposed" is an exaggeration here... Wikipedia's page for four vectors for example specifies it uses "lowercase bold for three-dimensional vectors, hats for three-dimensional unit vectors, capital bold for four dimensional vectors". I personally favor $\vec{u}$ for the spatial component of vectors, which more easily distinguishes the bold symbols as four-vectors. I agree that I could just write $u^\mu$ and avoid the issue altogether ($\mu$ is always taken to be in the range $0\dots 3$), but I think it's less elegant.

The inner product of 2 vectors is calculated using the metric tensor, which is defined to be non-degenerate, i. e. if $u \cdot v = 0$ for all vectors $v$, then $u$ is the $0$ vector. This means that if $F \neq 0$, $F \cdot u$ has to be non-zero for at least one vector $u$. If $F$ was dependent on $u$, then $F(u) \cdot u = 0$ for all $u$ would not lead to a contradiction.

Ok, that's clear and nails the mathematical reasoning a lot better so thank you. But, I was hoping to understand a bit better what constitutes $F$ being "dependent on $u$". Also, when you write that it wouldn't lead to a contradiction, you mean it doesn't necessarily lead to a contradiction right? My guess is that just being dependent on the four velocity doesn't automatically guarantee the four force being orthogonal to the four velocity, is it?

Good example of a force being dependent on $u$ is the Lorentz force - you can look up relativistic formulation of it and see that acceleration is dependent on velocity.
When I said that it does not lead to contradicition I was saying that because $F(u)$ is not the same vector for every $u$, $F(u) \cdot u = 0$ for every $u$ does not contradict non-degeneracy of metric tensor. You can see that $F(u) = k,u$ is dependent on $u$, but does not constitute valid force since $F(u) \cdot u \neq 0$ unless $u \cdot u = 0$.

Thank you, that reference (to the Lorentz force) is very helpful!
